# Sublime Text 3 android installation

Tags: android, installation, sublimetext3

Cannot get Sublime Text 3 installed on a android tablet.

Cannot find adequate instructions.

Need good Sublime install on my android tablet.

Comment: ST3 can be installed on OS X, Windows and Linux. There is no timeline for Android to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime can only be installed on Windows, MacOS or Linux, and further requires that the processor on the machine be `x86` `x86_64` or compatible (for example AMD chips would also work). Most notably that means that anything like a Raspberry PI, Arduino, or an Android device which runs on a different architecture (for example ARM, which is quite common in such scenarios) is not compatible.

In addition to that even if such a device was `x86` compatible it still requires the ability to install native Linux Desktop applications and have the appropriate libraries (e.g. GTK3) for Sublime to work; basically it has to support the notion of a full fledged desktop application.

An example of that would be on a ChromeBook running ChromeOS; on such devices if the architecture is Intel compatible and the ChromeBOok has a Linux container installed, Sublime will work there.